# Managing dependencies between layers

Tags: layers

I have multiple layers that has dependency with each other.

Such as: City; Courts; Lots; Front Lot; Buildings.
The polygon's "block" depends on the polygon's "City." Example dependency: Buildings-> Front Lot -> Lots -> Blocks -> City.

On my server I have installed the Oracle SDE.
He has the Esri SDK. With the "spatial functions" for Oracle.

I thought I'd solve this with the "spatial functions."
I think to check the intersection of the layers. As the example of the link:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_SQL_functions_used_with_ST_Geometry/006z0000003n000000/

In my future solution, when a building is in another district must update this value automatically.
Maybe even cut off part of a neighborhood that is outside the city limits.

What better way to manage these dependencies layers?

There is a ready tool?

Or API?

ADF/Python etc?

Or another solution ready?